# Aligning two set of points into a same reference point, centroid

Tags: r, cluster-computing

I have two sets of 2d points (in x,y coordinates). How can I align these two set of points into a same reference point (centroid)?

Let my two sets are

A

```
x     y
1     3
4     2
7     8
3     5
```

B

```
x     y
9     5
14    7
17    3
30    25
```

By centroid I mean: it is the mean position of all points in all the co-ordinate direction.

Could any one please suggest me how to do it using R.

Thanks in advance.

**Added later:**

```
data1<-data.frame(x=c(1,4,7,3), y=c(3,2,8,5))
data2<-data.frame(x=c(9,14,17,30), y=c(5,7,3,25))
```

The centroids of the clusters are :

```
m1=c(mean(data1[,1]),mean(data1[,2]))
m2=c(mean(data2[,1]),mean(data2[,2]))
```

Now I want to align (coinside) `m1` and `m2` and get all the cluster points with respect to the common
aligned centroid. How to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I solved my problem. I just subtract m1 from all the points of the first cluster and subtract m2 from all the points of the second cluster. So now both the centroids become (0,0) and all other points are arranged with respect to the common centroid (0,0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit late to the party, but:

- the technical term for aligning the origin is *centering*.
- if your groups are in different variables, you can use `scale`:

  ```
  data1<-data.frame(x=c(1,4,7,3), y=c(3,2,8,5))
  data2<-data.frame(x=c(9,14,17,30), y=c(5,7,3,25))

  scale (data1, center = TRUE, scale = FALSE)
  scale (data2, center = TRUE, scale = FALSE)
  ```
- if the groups are within the same data frame, `ave` can help (see also `aggregate`:

  ```
  data1$group <- "A"        
  data2$group <- "B"
  data <- rbind (data1, data2)

  data$x <- data$x - ave (data$x, data$group)
  data$y <- data$y - ave (data$y, data$group)
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Typically you would use kmeans to do something like this. Normally you would attempt to determine the optimal number of clusters but in your case if you are assuming just a global mean and therefore one cluster then something like this:

```
#Two datasets
data1<-data.frame(x=c(1,4,7,3), y=c(3,2,8,5))
data2<-data.frame(x=c(9,14,17,30), y=c(5,7,3,25))

#combine datasets into one data frame
comb.data<-rbind(data1,data2)

#find the center of the data by assuming there is only one
fit<-kmeans(comb.data, centers=1)

#print out coordinates of center:
fit$centers
```

You can also plot it with the cluster package with the above code and this added:

```
library(cluster)
clusplot(comb.data, fit$cluster, color=T)
```

More info can be found here http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/cluster.html but there's a thousand references for clustering in R depending on if your interests are biology, chemometrics, etc.

Comment: @RXander...Thanks for your attention and effort. I think the codes given by you is not exactly answering my question. You are taking mean of the combined data, but it is not in my case. I edited my question to convey what exactly I want. Could you please have a look and help me to answer the question. Thanks again.

Comment: please adress the question